# Do not repeat the last used image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make the next image that appears not repeat the last one that was used?

```
var imgs = new Array("https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/1.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/2.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/3.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/4.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/5.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/6.jpg");

function changeBg() {
        var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
        $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
};

setInterval(changeBg,10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the last one that was used and generate new ones until what you want holds true.

```js
var imgs = new Array("https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/1.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/2.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/3.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/4.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/5.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/6.jpg");

var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
var lastUsed = "";

function changeBg() {
    while(imgUrl !== lastUsed) 
      imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
    lastUsed = imgUrl;
};

setInterval(changeBg,10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the last used index and regenerate the random number if it matches it:

```
var lastIndex = -1;
function changeBg() {
    var index;
    do {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length);
    } while (index == lastIndex);
    var imgUrl = imgs[index];
    lastIndex = index;
    $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than selecting a random item from the array and checking if it has occurred, I suggest that you shuffle the array (to get a random selection) and then shift the first item off it. This will allow both a random and a unique selection of items and remove the current item from the available array. To allow the original array to be replenished, each item is pushed into a usedImages array and then the used images retruned to the original array when it is empty.

**Note that this will prevent the same item being replicated but it will also mutate the original array (although it replenishes it upon emptying the array).**

Since I don't have access to the images for the background - I am console.logging the url to demonstrate it is always unique and that the array is replenished. I have also shortened the interval to 3 seconds for demonstration purposes.

```js
var imgs = ["https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/1.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/2.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/3.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/4.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/5.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/6.jpg"];

var usedImages = [];
changeBg();

function changeBg() {
  shuffle(imgs);
  var imgUrl = imgs.shift();
  console.log(imgUrl);
  $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
  
  usedImages.push(imgUrl)
  if(imgs.length== 0 ) {
    imgs= usedImages;
    usedImages=[]
    };  
  
};


function shuffle(array) {
 var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
 while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
  array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
  array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
 }
 return array;
}


setInterval(changeBg, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```